# Problems with appearance in iphone

Tags: iphone

i have tryied this for many hours now but dont get it to work.

Please se the example image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCvNd.png

The iPhone only shows "Content" but i want it also to show the left and right spaces.

thank you in advance !

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get your app to do?  What is the relevant code?  How does that image help?

Comment: Its not an app, in iphone view safari only show the white content and not the space that is on the left and right. I want to show the whole page and not only the "content" if you under stand what i mean :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a webpage you probably want to set the width of the left/right to some fixed value and the content to 100%/auto (don't remember) or make all the widths with percentage...